# Replicating results with multiway clustering

Tags: multiple-regression, clustered-standard-errors

I am trying to replicate table 2 of [Nunn and Wantchekon (2011)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.101.7.3221) (the paper data is available online).

It involves a linear regression with fixed effects and adjusting for two-way clustering.

The code I wrote is:

```
library(haven)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(lfe)
Nunn_Wantchekon_AER_2011 <- read_dta("R/datasets/NUNN_WANTCHEKON_AER_2011_REPLICATION_FILES/Nunn_Wantchekon_AER_2011.dta")
out <- felm(trust_relatives # trust_relatives trust_neighbors intra_group_trust inter_group_trust trust_local_council
            ~ ln_export_area 
            + factor(isocode) # country fixed effects
            + age + age2 + male + urban_dum + factor(occupation) + factor(religion) # individual controls
            + factor(living_conditions) + factor(education)  # individual controls
            + district_ethnic_frac + frac_ethnicity_in_district
            # + explorer_contact + railway_contact + malaria_ecology
            # + school_present + electricity_present + piped_water_present + sewage_present + health_clinic_present # public goods controls
            | 0 | 0 | ethnicity + district
            , data=Nunn_Wantchekon_AER_2011)
summary(out)
```

Now, this is producing the correct coefficient estimates, but not the correct standard errors.

For example, I am getting a coefficent associated with `ln_export_area` of `-0.1330 (0.03149)`, while the one reported in the paper is `−0.133 (0.037)`.

I am also getting two confusing console messages when I run the script:

```
Warning message:
In newols(mm, nostats = nostats[1], exactDOF = exactDOF, onlyse = onlyse,  :
  Negative eigenvalues set to zero in multiway clustered variance matrix. See felm(...,psdef=FALSE)

Warning message:
In chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) :
  the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

What is going on? Am I doing the multiway clustering std error adjustment correctly? What do the warning messages mean?